# A method of a base class that calls another method defined in the same base class may end up calling a method of a derived class that overrides it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading python documentaitin at: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

I am having trouble understanding the following:

> Because methods have no special privileges when calling other methods of the
>   same object, a method of a base class that calls another method
>   defined in the same base class may end up calling a method of a
>   derived class that overrides it. (For C++ programmers: all methods in
>   Python are effectively virtual.)

Say base class X has method A that calls method B in the same base class.

Now a derived class Y, say has method B, and user invokes Y.A(). Then, method A from Class X will be invoked and it will call method B from Class Y? Is this what author is trying to say?

Comment: Yes (`Y().A()` will call `Y.B`)

Comment: And name mangling can be used to prevent this right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this it what he means

```
In [8]: class A:
   ...:     def foo(self):
   ...:         print ('foo')
   ...:         self.bar()
   ...:     def bar(self):
   ...:         print ('bar')
   ...:

In [9]: class B(A):
   ...:     def bar(self):
   ...:         print('bar but in b')
   ...:

In [10]: obj = B()

In [11]: obj.foo()
foo
bar but in b
```

In line 11, obj.foo() calls `foo` in class B, since its non existent, it goes to foo in class A, which then calls `bar`, since B has `bar` it calls it instead of `bar` in class A

If you have access to a debugger like pycharm it would be easier to follow it step by step